# How to get the data used to calculate OOB score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I know that you can get the OOB score in the sklearn Random Forest by setting oob_score=True in the RandomForestRegressor function. I am not sure if this is possible but is there a way to get the observations and predictions used in calculating this OOB score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stored under the attribute `oob_prediction_`, and the prediction is obtained by averaging predictions across all your trees where the row or observation is OOB.

For example the first 10 OOB predictions for the first 10 observations:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(n_features=4, n_informative=2,
                       random_state=0, shuffle=False)
regr = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0,oob_score=True)
regr.fit(X, y)

regr.oob_prediction_[:10]
```